# Getting last message of each user from db

Tags: mysql

I have a procedure that returning the last message and the user of that message.

I have a lot of messages in the messages table. The problem that this query takes more than 30 seconds to return the results.

```
Select user_user_id, max(message_message_id) as message_id 
From vw_messages 
Where page_page_id = 176
Group by user_user_id
Order by message_id desc
Limit 0, 15
```

Is there a way to improve the efficiency of the query?

**EDIT**

I think it takes a long time because in order to get the page_id on each message I need to do two left joins - message.user_id=> user.page_id.

Should I just add a property of page_id on each message?

Comment: How many is *a lot*? Thousands, millions? What indexes do you have?

Comment: Probably Thousands to Ten Thousand.
I think the problem is that my view is including two left joins to get the page_id.

Message.user_id->user_id.page_id.

Should I just add a property of page_id to the messages table?

Comment: If you're also using a view, this one is going to be down to indexes, as mentioned above.  The indexes should ideally be on the fields that you are asking the DB to scan through, so whatever is on your join and any categorical 'filters' beyond that.

Comment: Put your ***complete*** query in your question, as well as exact information about your indexes.  Ten thousand records is nothing unless you inadvertently create  a Cartesian product somewhere along the way.